Confusion about time horizons for components of the variance risk premium
My original understanding of how to compute the variance risk premium is that it is given by the following
$$VRP_{t,t+\Delta t} = IV_{t,t+\Delta t} - RV_{t,t+\Delta t}$$
such that the realized volatility must be "pulled back" to make the quantities contemporaneous.
This agreed upon with another post previously posted in Quant SE:
Computing the Variance Risk Premium
And the above makes sense logically...
However, this is contradicted by Bollerslev et al. (2009, RFS) "Expected Stock Returns and Variance Risk Premia", whom states that the variance risk premium is given by:
$$VRP_{t,t+\Delta t} = IV_{t,t+\Delta t} - RV_{t-\Delta t,t}$$

Main Question: Why are the periods for the risk-neutral expectation and true realized variances not contemporaneous when being used to calculate the variance risk premium? Which method is correct? Or are they just different methods used?

I agree with your original definition and interpretation. But in this case, as the authors state:
"Compared to the variance premium in Equation (16), the variance difference has the advantage that IVt and RVt , and therefore VRP t , are directly observable at time t." ...

Please edit the post to include a more complete reference to Bollerslev et al. (2009, RFS). Is it this one? Thank you.

Thanks @Kermittfrog and Richard Hardy, updated to include the details.

Simple answer is, there is no right answer. IV is market expectation of future RV, plus some risk premium. When you compare past IV to past RV, you compare an ex-ante expectation to one ex-post realized path, among many other possible. So you can't pinpoint the ex-ante risk premium component on that single path. But you can do long term averages to average out the singleness of each path.
When you compare current IV to past RV, you make the strong assumption that past RV is a good proxy for future RV, which partly makes sense (vol works in regimes and recent behavior is likely to persist in the near future), and partly doesn't (ignores future events, mean reversion, and the fact that the world changes)
